# How to check if a 3rd party Library uses Push Notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification

When I upload my app for TestFlight I get the warning email about a missing push notification entitlement. I don't use push notifications in my app and I don't want to add the entitlement just to remove the warning without knowing what's causing it.

I assume it must be in a library I'm using. How would I check this? I've googled around and haven't found a good way to find out.

I've tried `grep "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes" -R .` and `grep "resgisterUserNotificationSettings" -R .`.
No results.

Comment: What files are you running `grep` on?

Comment: @rmaddy The whole project directory. Edit: including my Pods directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some digging on [Apple's notification dev page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9) and came up with the following grep:

`grep "application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:" -R Pods/`

Got hits in Firebase Analytics and Firebase InstanceID binary files. So even though I'm not using Firebase messaging it looks like Firebase/Core and Firebase/Analytics use push notifications.

So to answer my own question:

**Grep for "Notification" in your Pod folder and narrow down the search from there.** But do be careful not to get mislead doing this. As stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingLocalAndPushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH3-SW1):

> Note: Push notifications have no functional connection to broadcast notifications or key-value observing notifications.

Comment: So what did you do to prevent the warning mails from Apple ?